# C# DLLImport converted to VB.NET DLLImport...what am I missing?

Tags: vb.net, interop, pinvoke, dllimport, c#-to-vb.net

In C# I have this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetDesktopWindow")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
```

I tried to convert to VB.NET thus:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetDesktopWindow")>
Function GetDesktopWindow() As IntPtr
End Function
```

But I am getting an error...
"Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute cannot be applied to instance method."

Can some explain what I need to do to fix this, and even better, tell me WHY?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You forgot to convert the `static` keyword from the C# declaration to VB.NET. That's what the error message is telling you. Unless you have a static method, you're declaring an instance method, and the `DllImportAttribute` cannot be applied to an instance method.

The VB.NET equivalent of `static` is `Shared`. So your declaration should look like this:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetDesktopWindow")>
Shared Function GetDesktopWindow() As IntPtr
End Function
```

I feel compelled to point out a couple of other things:

- It's unnecessary to specify the `EntryPoint` when your function declaration has the same name. Not that it hurts anything to do so anyway, but I feel that it keeps down duplication and reduces the chances of error if you omit it.
- P/Invoke declarations like this should generally go into a static class with a name like `NativeMethods` (StyleCop enforces this guideline). In VB.NET, static classes are called modules. So it would look like this:

  ```
  Module NativeMethods
      <DllImport("user32.dll")>
      Shared Function GetDesktopWindow() As IntPtr
      End Function
  End Module
  ```
- In older versions of VB (pre-VB 10, shipped with VS 2010), you needed line continuation characters in order to break up function declarations onto multiple lines. Those ugly warts make it look like this:

  ```
  Module NativeMethods
      <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
      Shared Function GetDesktopWindow() As IntPtr
      End Function
  End Module
  ```

And finally, **be very careful about how you use the desktop window** returned by the `GetDesktopWindow` function! [Lots of people abuse it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/24/79212.aspx), and most of the time when I see people trying to retrieve a handle to it, that's a sign that they're already doing it wrong. (Not saying you are, since I can't see the rest of your code, just something to be aware of!)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I am using it to get a screenshot when there is an error in the application. :-)

Comment: To add one more thing...if I put them into a module, it would not allow me to use the Shared keyword, presumably because a module already is static and it is redundant to declare the function as Shared.